# Permission denied when running shell module in ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, permission-denied

I need to run command1 as foouser. The path environment for command1 is set in .some_env file. So I need to source it first.

```
- name: Run something
  become_user: foouser
  become_method: sudo   
  shell: . /path/to/dir/.some_env; command1
```

However this erros with

```
/bin/sh: /path/to/dir/.some_env: Permission denied
```

The file permission looks good:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 foouser foogroup 2107 Mar 20 07:08 .some_env
```

I tried the followings:

- using "source" instead of .   - didn't help
- added a shebang in the top of the env file - didn't help

Why does it say permission denied?

Comment: are you sure foouser has execute permissions on the dir which is hosting .some_env? for example I can have a file in /some/path/foo.env. and while `foo.env` might have all the right permissions i also need there to be permissions for foo to access the dir and to execute in it

Comment: `The file permission` And directory permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You might have problem with permissions, sourcing a file does not need execute privilege(x). check this playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false



  tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/a
      state: present
      line: export n="hello there"
      create: yes

  - shell:
      executable: /bin/bash
      cmd: |
        set -e
        test -r /tmp
        test -r /tmp/a
        source /tmp/a
        echo $n
    register: _t

  - debug:
      var: _t.stdout
```

in `shell` task I check for:

- directory is readable for me
- file is readable for me
- then I source the file

output of this playbook is:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [shell] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "_t.stdout": "hello there"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Just checked - the directory has read permissions as well.
drwxr-xr-x

Comment: What will show you if You run `cat /path/to/dir/.some_env` directly from shell with user `foouser`

Comment: Everything works from shell, in an interactive shell session. I can switch user to foouser, I can source the env file I can cat it. The problem is only when I ran the ansible shell task. I increased debug level in ansible playbook. There is a lot more irrelevant mumbo jumbo log prior to the error message,  but the actual error message part is just exactly the same Permission Denied.

Comment: have You tried with `executable` parameter on `/bin/bash`? usually `/bin/sh` is linked to something else and that might not be `bash`.

Comment: I tried adding args: executable: /bin/bash (also /bin/sh) - but it didn't work still.